# how to show multiple composite view in single view backbone marionette js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to call multiple composite view in single view plz help me.

```
var view = new applic({
collection: {collection1:CollectionList,collectionList2:CollectionList2}, 
model: new Model(data)
                    });
```

Comment: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html

Comment: i want to show it only using composite view and collection view